# How to loop through an array of strings backwards x amount of times and start over when the end is reached?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to loop through an array of months 11 times backwards. Basically I have a current month (September 2019) and I want to go back 11 months thus ending up at October 2018.  I have looked at so many code snippets but none capture the whole 'starting over' portion. The point of it all is to push these months into a dropdown menu. Thus having the current month and the previous 11 months.

I have already tried this code snippet. It just goes forward. When I set it up to where it goes backwards there is this endless loop that kills my Chrome.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.getMonth() + " is the index");

var index = monthNames[d.getMonth()];
console.log(index + ' is the month');
let monthIndex = monthNames.indexOf(index);
var n = 11

var result = [];

for (var i = monthIndex, len = monthNames.length; i <= monthIndex + n; i++) {
    result.push(monthNames[(i + len) % len]);
}


console.log(result.join(", "));
```

It is going forwards in months when I want it to start at September and go backwards and end up at October.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe duplicate the array like `['1','2','3','1','2','3',]` and then you can start full 12 month from the first month you find.

Comment: your code is rather verbose for what is needed - but essentially, if you want to go backwards, not forwards, you need to change the `i++` in your loop to `i--`. (You may have to make some adjustments to the index in some cases, at the boundary - I haven't looked at that yet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much different than what suggested above but bit simpler to understand

```js
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentMonthIndex = currentDate.getMonth();
var result = [];
var monthLength = 12;

for (var i = currentMonthIndex; i < monthLength; i--) {
  result.push(monthNames[i]);

  if (result.length === monthLength) {
    break;
  }

  if (i === 0) {
    i = monthLength;
  }  
}


console.log(result.join(", "));
```

Comment: Thank you (and everyone else) so much for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could take the actual month as offset and subtract the index and get the rest with the remainder for the value of the month names.

```js
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    offset = new Date().getMonth(),
    length = 12,
    result = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => monthNames[(12 + offset - i) % 12]);

console.log(result.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Python-like logic, you can try [JavaScript Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```js
const monthNames = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
];

const months = new Proxy(monthNames, {
  get(target, prop) {
    if (!isNaN(prop)) {
      prop = parseInt(prop, 10);
      if (prop < 0) {
        prop += target.length;
      }
    }
    return target[prop];
  }
})


let d = new Date()
let start = d.getMonth() - 1
let n = 11
let end = start - n,
    result = []


for(let c = start; c >= end; c--){
  result.push(months[c])
}

console.log(result.join(", "))
```

This way you will only need the starting month and subtract 11 from itself, and you can easily call that range from `months`. (e.g. start 5, end 5-11)

Answer (score 0):

One approach that works is to subtract one from the index each time, checking when you're at 0 to loop back to the end, and stop the loop when you get to one more than the starting point. Note that this will bring the loop to a premature end because your ending condition is true at the start - so you need to start at one less than that, having prepopulated the array with the current month.

I've also removed a lot of the unnecessary repetitions in your original code. The below is, I freely admit, not particular elegant, but it works and should be easily understandable.

```js
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var startMonth = new Date().getMonth();

var result = [monthNames[startMonth]];

if (startMonth == 0) {
    startMonth = monthNames.length;
}

for (var i = startMonth - 1; i != startMonth; i = (i == 0) ? monthNames.length : (i - 1)) {
    result.push(monthNames[i]);
}


console.log(result.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];


const octoberIndex = monthNames.findIndex(month => month === "October");
const monthsFromOctoberToSeptember = monthNames.slice(octoberIndex, monthNames.length)
.concat(monthNames.slice(0, octoberIndex));

const result = monthsFromOctoberToSeptember.reverse();

console.log(result.join(', '));
```

> September, August, July, June, May, April, March, February, January,
>   December, November, October